# How to define the type of limit value in Scala?

Tags: scala

I need to restrict the caller of the function to only use the string "asc" or "desc", so I want to use a constant to define the type.

When I use typescript, I can do like this:

```
function test(order: "asc" | "desc") {
    // ...
}
```

Then order can only be either "asc" or "desc". So how to define `order` in Scala?

Answer (score 3):

```
sealed trait order
case object asc extends order
case object desc extends order
```

**Automatic conversion**

You can automatically convert `String` to `order` using an implicit conversion:

```
object order {
  implicit def string2order(s: String): order = s match {
    case "asc" => asc
    case "desc" => desc
  }
}
```

Once this is defined you can pass a `String` to a method that takes `order` and it will be automatically converted. (There will be a `MatchError` if an invalid value is given).

Note that using strings in this way is not recommended; just use the case objects directly for better type safety.

---

Note that I have preserved the case of `order`, `asc` and `desc` to match your question, but Scala convention is to use capital letters for class and object names (`Order`, `Asc`, `Desc`)

Comment: I need to restrict the caller of the function to only use the string "asc" or "desc". eg:`function test(order: "asc" | "desc")`, because the string constant "esc" or "desc" is used in the code.

Comment: You would then need to adjust these callers to first try to parse the strings into these enum values, probably with pattern matching. But this is how you get type safety. Avoid magic String constants in your code, push them to input/output code.

Answer (score 2):

so sadly we don't quite yet have Union Types like this. they're slotted to be in dotty though not for singleton types as in your example afaik.

The most common way it to employ an sealed trait hierarchy like this

```
sealed trait Order
final case object Asc extends Order
final case object Desc extends Order
```

It is important that the trait is final and the case classes/object final so that the compiler can do exhaustiveness checks

```
val ord:Order = Asc
val ord2:Order = Desc
```

are the only 2 possible cases because neither the trait nor the case classes/objects can be extended any further. that means that every instance of type `Order` has to be either `Asc` or `Desc`

```
ord match {
    case Asc => ???
    case Desc => ???
}
```

to pattern match on an `Order` and then do whatever

EDIT: The "anonymous" way to do this would be through the `Either[A, B]` datatype though that'd also require the use of singleton types (which you can get through some libraries like shapeless) or you'd just end up with `Either[String, String]` which is meh.

Comment: In my code, I need to limit the caller to only use the string "asc" or "desc", but I can't use constants to define types, right?

Comment: that is correct but it should be fairly easy to write a pair of functions `Order => String` and one `String => Either[Error, Order]` that do the mapping from and to `String`

Comment: well it is somewhat correct, there are singleton types but you need specialized libraries for that.